How to get metadata for Bandcamp music into MacOS Music
I like music in WAV files.  When I import from a CD, MacOS Music goes to the Gracenote database and updates lots of handy information about the tracks from the CD.  When I buy music in Bandcamp, MacOS music doesn't do that.  The information is available, but it's written into the Bandcamp filenames.  Example filename:

"I Think Like Midnight - Microtonal Honkytonk - 02 Spring Looks Mint.wav"

The first part, before "-" is the band name, "I Think Like Midnight".  The next part is the album name, "Microtonal Honkytonk", then the track number, 2, and finally the song name "Spring Looks Mint".
At present, when I buy music from Bandcamp, I have to type that information into the relevant Music fields by hand.  That's not very pleasant.

Is there a way to force MacOS Music to update the data on the songs from the usual Gracenote database with Bandcamp music I've already imported?

Is there some kind of preparation I can do to the Bandcamp files to make Music treat the import process so that it's the same as when a CD is imported--so that Music goes out to Gracenote to get the metadata?

What format is the metadata that MacOS pulls in?  If I know the format, and there is a way to get Music to read a file containing the data (a big "if), then I can probably write a little code to convert the information in Bandcamp filenames into the data that Music wants to see.



You may have some luck with ffmpeg writing the metadata into the file itself - but I am not sure.

Thanks @hym3242!  I'll look into it.

And the metadata format is likely called ID3/ID3v2. As shown here  https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/0757b3d8b989fe433979db2ea7d95a01

Several command-line programs can write ID3 tags, including ffmpeg, id3tag, id3v2, mid3v2, and eyeD3; all are available in HomeBrew.  (However, I haven't yet found one that can cope with all tags; some can only write common tags; some can't write custom genres; and mid3v2 — the only one that can write the grouping tag — appends a trailing null to the comment and lyrics, which causes problems.)
